Helm chart value is not read from values YAML file
I'm trying to install NGINX Ingress Controller Helm chart in my Kubernetes cluster. I want controller.allowSnippetAnnotations variable to be true.
I have created a values.yml file with this content:
controller:
  allowSnippetAnnotations: true

Then, I run this:
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx -f values.yml

It installs it but controller.allowSnippetAnnotations is still false (default value).
$ helm show values ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx | grep allowSnippetAnnotations
  allowSnippetAnnotations: false

I'm starting with Helm and I wonder what am I doing wrong.

It's picking up the values.yaml in the chart.
Change the name of the values file to something like dev-values.yaml.
or just set that single value
helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx --set controller.allowSnippetAnnotations=true

$ helm template ingress-nginx charts/ingress-nginx  --set controller.allowSnippetAnnotations=true | grep allow-snippet-annotations
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"


I tried and same happens. Value is not reassigned.

@Héctor I just tested it
